# Java / Scala - how to convert string to long?

Tags: string, scala

I am suprised by this error : 
How should I transform my timestamp string into a TimeStamp object ?

```
val a = new Timestamp( "1485783591".toDouble)
a
Out[157]:
Name: Unknown Error
Message: <console>:79: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Long
       val a = new Timestamp( "1485783591".toDouble)
                                           ^
StackTrace:
```

## Edit

Looking for current timestamp here : http://www.timestamp.fr/?
I got the value 1485783591 =  30/1/2017  14:39:51

But my java program doesn't :

```
val a = new Timestamp("1485783591".toLong)
a
```

output :

```
=> 1970-01-18 04:43:03.591
```

why ??

Comment: Longs don't contain decimals.

Comment: And next time - don't use screenshots, copy and paste the code and the exception. Images are not searchable, nor do they help reproducing the error.

Comment: Which class should it be casted to  ? Double doesn't seem to be accepted by TimeStamp

Comment: The timestamp from that website is likely in seconds while the Timestamp object takes milliseconds.  Try Multiplying the value by 1000

Comment: You've _completely_ changed the meaning of your question with the edit. Don't do that. But to answer your revised question `new Timestamp( "1485783591".toDouble)` passes a Double to Timestamp because that's what you said (`toDouble`). Presumably you meant `toLong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.sql.Timestamp` (a subclass of `java.util.Date`) uses milliseconds for time while the Unix timestamp counts seconds.  If you have a Unix timestamp you need to multiply it by 1000 (and divide by 1000 to get a Unix timestamp from a Java Date).

Answer (score 2):

As the page says, it considers the timestamp to be the number of *seconds* since midnight January 1 1970. Just looking at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp-long-) tells you `new Timestamp` expects the number of *milli*-seconds. So multiply it by 1000. `Timestamp` is also unlikely to be the type you want to use: it's SQL-specific. Consider `java.time.*` types instead.